# Python - transform time format in datatime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-analysis

Have dd-mm-yy in "date" column

```
05-01-15
```

need yyyy-mm-dd

```
2015-01-05
```

Solved with

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d-%m-%y', errors='coerce')
```

Has it another solution?

Comment: @Sayse there must be plenty of answers to this, but the link posted is different because it's about python in general, and the question is about pandas.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 

date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print("date and time:",date_time)
```

Or have a closer look at strftime [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: Excuse me, may be I'm didn't got it, but why "now"? I have 2015 in the table. And all what's necessary to change the order of D-M-Y to Y-M-D.

Answer (score -1):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Will transform your custom format to pandas recognized datetime, which you will be able to use for calculations.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde, I'll check the link and provided more context in the meantime.